# number_in_month exercise (SML error: operator and operand don't agree when comparing integer in list to an integer)

Tags: sml, typechecking

I am new to Standard ML, and can't figure out why I am getting this type mismatch error:

```
fun number_in_month (month : int, dates : int list) =                                            
    if null dates                                                                                
    then 0                                                                                       
    else if (month = (hd (tl (hd dates))))            
    then number_in_month(month, (tl dates)) + 1
    else number_in_month(month, (tl dates))
```

Evaluating this function results in the following error:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]     
 5  operator domain: 'Z list                                                                       
 6  operand:         int                                                                           
 7  in expression:                                                                                 
 8    tl (hd dates)
```

However, at the REPL, if i do the following:

```
val x = [[84, 12, 23], [83, 01, 18]]
12 = (hd (tl (hd x)))                    (*  -> val it = true : bool *)
```

I am not sure what the type-checking rules are in this case, and I don't see why the same expression would work on the REPL but not when I try to evaluate the subexpression in the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting the head of the tail of the head of a list. Your `x` (in the REPL) is
a `int list list` (a list of a list of ints). But your function definition declares it
as an `int list`. Re-declaring `number_in_month` with `dates: int list list` should solve 
your problem:

```
fun number_in_month (month : int, dates : int list list) =  
   ...
```

It works as you expect in the REPL because you define `x` without explicitly declaring it's type. SML infers that the type of x is `int list list` which is why `(hd (tl (hd x)))` 
passes the type-checker.

**UPDATE**

(was trying to add this right when stackoverflow went down)

If you're interested, here's some ideas on how you could re-write your code to make it
more ML-ish:

First, you could use pattern matching:

```
fun number_in_month (month: int, []) = 0
  | number_in_month (month: int, ([y,m,d]::rest)) = 
      if month = m then number_in_month(month, rest) + 1
      else number_in_month(month, rest)
```

So `number_in_month` takes a tuple of a month and a list of dates, which is logically either `[]` or `([y,m,d]::rest)`. This is compatible with how you've chosen to represent dates
(as a list of ints), but this will compile with a `match nonexhaustive` warning. That makes sense, because what happens if you pass in `dates` as `[[84], [83]]`? The pattern match approach at least warns you about this, but with code like `(hd (tl (hd dates)))` you'll get
a runtime error though your program has type-checked successfully. You could add another
pattern match for lists of dates where the date has less/more than 3 elements, but if
possible, it might be cleaner to represent dates as *tuples* of 3 ints.

```
 type date = (int * int * int)
```

Then you could have:

```
fun number_in_month (month: int, []: date list) = 0
  | number_in_month (month: int, ((y,m,d)::rest)) = 
      if month = m then number_in_month(month, rest) + 1
      else number_in_month(month, rest)
```

Also, if you'd rather reuse code, you could try higher-order functions (such as `foldr`):

```
fun number_in_month (month: int, dates: date list) =
  foldl (fn ((_,m,_), c) => if m = month then c+1 else c) 0 dates
```

Or

```
fun number_in_month (month: int, dates: date list) =
  length (List.filter (fn (_,m,_) => m = month) dates)
```

More than you asked for, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out, but you beat me to the punch!